# Sleep until specified time

Tags: datetime, timer, shell, scheduled-tasks

It's sometimes useful to pause until a specified time (but inconvenient to use `at` or the like), so I wrote a tiny script to wait until a user-specified time point is reached.

I use this when I want to keep the output of preceding and subsequent commands together, but I don't mind blocking the current terminal.  Quite often, this would be <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile` when I want to wait until after new source code/data have been uploaded, but still have the results in a compilation-mode buffer.

Although it's a very short script, my time at Code Review has taught me that almost any program has something that can be improved, so please make your suggestions!

```
#!/bin/sh

# Sleep until the specified time

# Accepts any date/time format accepted by 'date'

# Assumes GNU date and GNU sleep

die() {
    echo "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 TIME"
}


test $# = 1 || die $(usage)

case "$1" in
    --version)
        echo "sleep_until version 1.0"
        exit 0
        ;;
    --help)
        usage
        exit 0
        ;;
    -*)
        die "Unrecognised option: $1"
        ;;
    *)
        end=$(date -d "$1" +%s.%N)
        now=$(date +%s.%N)
        test ${end%.*} -gt ${now%.*} || die "$1 is in the past!"
        exec sleep $(echo $end $now - p | dc )
        ;;
esac
```

### Notes:

- We need GNU `date` for its `-d` option and a good range of input formats.
- GNU `sleep` handles fractional seconds; we could remove `.%N` from the date formats to work with traditional/POSIX `sleep`.
- I've used `dc` for the arithmetic so we can use plain `sh` rather than requiring a more heavyweight shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a program *comment* it is said that the program

```
# Accepts any date/time format accepted by 'date'
```

That information should be printed with the *usage help,* plus one or two examples. Something like

```
$ ./sleep_until.sh --help
Usage: ./sleep_until.sh TIME

    TIME can be any date/time as accepted by date(1).

Examples:

    ...
```

That'll save me from looking into the source code (and possibly from
looking up `man date`) in order to figure out the correct parameters.

---

Due to the truncation in

```
test ${end%.*} -gt ${now%.*} || die "$1 is in the past!"
```

there is a (albeit small) chance that a valid date is not recognized.
This can be avoided by computing the delay first, and then checking
it to be positive (e.g. as in [How to compare to floating point number in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24728)):

```
end=$(date -d "$1" +%s.%N)
now=$(date +%s.%N)
delay=$(echo $end - $now | bc)
test 1 -eq $(echo "$delay > 0" | bc) || die "$1 is in the past!"
exec sleep $delay
```

Note: I'm using `bc` rather than `dc` here just because I needed it for the check `$delay > 0` and found a `bc`-based solution first (and then I did not want to use two different tools). Also I am a little bit more familiar with `bc`. Some criteria are given in the Unix & Linux question [*How is bc different from dc?*](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/124518), such as “*bc is standardised by POSIX and so is probably the more portable of the two*.”

Answer (score 1):

The substitution in the final `exec` line can be simplified.  Instead of making a pipeline with `echo`, we can provide input to `dc` as a command argument:

```
        exec sleep $(dc -e "$end $now -p")
```

---

I always recommend setting `-e` and `-u` options for shell scripts.  So add at the beginning:

```
set -eu
```

This is particularly important, to ensure that we fail neatly when the argument is not understood by `date`.

I think I missed this because I thought that these were Bashisms, but they are actually [specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/set.html).

---

Consider adding a `--verbose` option to print the sleep duration (in seconds) and target time - this could be valuable with some of the relative times supported by `date`.  The argument parsing and checking would need to be reworked, as the simple `$# = 1` check would no longer be adequate.

Also, accept `-h` as a synonym for `--help`.

---

## Improved code

Applying these suggestions and those from the other answer, I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Assumes GNU date and GNU sleep

set -eu

die() {
    echo "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}

usage() {
    cat <<EOF
Usage:  $0 [-v|--verbose] TIME
or  $0 --version

Sleep until the specified time.

    TIME can be any date/time as accepted by date(1).

Examples:
    $0 3:14
    $0 'next Tuesday'
EOF
}

verbose=false

while [ "${1+y}" ]
do
    case "$1" in
        --version)
            echo "sleep_until version 1.1"
            exit 0
            ;;
        -h|--help)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        -v|--verbose)
            verbose=true
            shift
            ;;
        -*)
            die "Unrecognised option: $1"
            ;;
        *)
            test \! "${2+y}" || die "Extra arguments after time"
            end=$(date -d "$1" +%s.%N)
            now=$(date +%s.%N)
            duration=$(dc -e "$end $now -p")
            case "$duration" in
                -*) die "$1 is in the past!";;
            esac
            if $verbose
            then
                printf 'Sleeping for %g seconds until ' $duration
                date -d "$1"
            fi
            exec sleep $duration
            ;;
    esac
done

# If we reach here, we didn't get any non-option argument
die "No time specified"
```